# New Ubuntu install. Still have old Ubuntu install on old drive?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, delete, reinstall

2yrs ago I bought an cheap Windows laptop to install Ubuntu on. I installed Ubuntu and formatted/removed Windows completely. The install went great and the laptop worked great. Last year I decided to upgrade that laptop: I installed an M2 drive (and some more ram).

When I upgraded I decided to make the M2 my boot drive. I installed Ubuntu on the new drive and acted as if the old one was never there. The install went great, and Ubuntu has been running great on the M2 (currently running 20.04 LTS).

The laptop still has the orignal 1TB HDD in it (with Ubuntu?) and I never interact with because everything I do is on the M2. I mounted it in /Media today and when viewing in the Terminal I found the whole old stack (/bin, /boot, /lib, /sys, /home, etc...) all still there. It is an awful amount of space to never use.

How can/Should I delete all this stuff so I can use that drive as a basic 2nd HDD?
(Should I install "wipe"? Are there terrible ways I could screw this up, rendering the 1TB drive unusable? I don't even care if Ubuntu boot-style stuff stays on the drive in some other partition (as I think it is now), I just want to be able to use the drive, and not get confused by huge old jungle of mirror-image folders).

Comment: If it's mounted on /media, then the bin directory will be /media/bin, the sbin found in /media/sbin.  Deleting those directories (ie. what you see in /media) won't impact the current system as the paths won't match your expected paths unless you've done extra things you've not mentioned. You haven't told us your release, or how you're viewing the data (terminal? a file manager? which file manager?) but I'd just `rm` whatever you don't want below the /media or directory you mounted it in. You don't need additional software to do it in my opinion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing an Ubuntu installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277838/removing-an-ubuntu-installation)

Comment: Unplug the old HDD, If everything is still working in a week, reformat it.

Comment: Thanks everyone and especially @guiverc. I got in there and just rm -r'd everything and then changed the permissions on the drive. Also added an entry to the fstab table so it automounts on boot. Am happy with my new added space!