# Reinstall Ubuntu on other disk with Windows dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

I am new to Linux and I have just installed a dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows.
Unfortunately Ubuntu was installed on the hard disk and not on my SSD.
Can I just boot with the Live-USB and remove the Ubuntu partitions with Gparted?
Next, I would simply install Ubuntu on the SSD.
Do I still need to repair the Windows boot loader (which you would have to do if Ubuntu were removed)?
Are there other things I should consider?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing an Ubuntu installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277838/removing-an-ubuntu-installation) and [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/)

Comment: You can use GParted to copy the Ubuntu partition from the HDD and paste it on free space of the SSD, **Use Windows Disk Manager** to create the free space on the SSD, not GParted. You will need to edit grub.cfg and fstab with the new Ubuntu's partition UUID. and depending on the location of the bootloader reinstall GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, first, if you can boot into both OS's then you are good and at this point, you just want to have Ubuntu on the drive you originally wanted, right? Do you have the unwanted Ubuntu on its own partition that is safe to delete? If so, that is what I did and I installed Ubuntu on a its own partition completely separate from anything windows and when I wanted to remove it, I booted into the BIOS so I could boot into Windows directly from the boot options and then just deleted the ubuntu partitions, BUT THIS WILL REMOVE GRUB BOOTLOADER, so you will need to install Ubuntu right after or if you want to use Windows you will need to switch what to boot from in the BIOS so Windows will work when you boot the computer. If it is easier for you, GParted is better, but make sure to only delete the Linux partitions so make sure to double-check what you are about to delete by the file system type as Windows will never use ext as its file system type. Then I would install Ubuntu right after so you can get grub back, have ubuntu on the drive you want and be able to easily boot into either OS when turning on the computer. Please post if you have any questions before you start as I would rather you have a clear picture of what to do vs you losing data you needed by accident. On a personal note, I love GParted and use it often so you can use Windows to modify the partitions or GParted, but GParted is a better tool. Just make sure to be 100000% sure the drive you are about to delete, wipe, or nuke is what you want gone forever.