# Wipe-clean Ubuntu installation

Tags: uninstall, thinkpad, usb-installation

I recently bought a Thinkpad carbon X1 gen9 with Ubuntu preinstalled.
The preinstalled Ubuntu have some problems (see [this forum](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/X1-Carbon-Gen-9-Ubuntu-support-OEM-image-and-instructions/m-p/5096435?page=6))
and I was thinking of trying Debian.

As soon as I try to boot from the USB stick that has an image of Debian I am "thrown" into grub and I am unable to do anything else (I guess lack of knowledge).

Now, I thought that I try another distro, and tried to boot up Kubuntu. The result was that Kubuntu never loaded and something like a recovery mode of Ubuntu was triggered, resulting into a fresh Ubuntu installation. (see also [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/paavc6/thinkpad_x1_gen_9_wont_boot_from_ysb/) where the same happened)

I have the feeling that this is related to some configuration from Ubuntu/Lenovo, triggering a recovery mode. As [this post] suggests, completely deleting Ubuntu did the job for him/her, so I was wondering how I can format from an Ubuntu installation.

Thank you

Comment: Are you actually booting those various USB installers successfully? It's hard to tell from your description. A successful boot of a Debian installer should give you a Debian screen with a big Debian logo and Debian install options. If not, then seems like a How-do-I-select-boot-device-in-BIOS question that's not related to Ubuntu. Ubuntu does not muck around with your BIOS boot selection options.

Comment: Yes I am. I have done successfully this procedure multiple times, on multiple machines. I was actually in doubt in the beginning whether the Debian installer was properly burned, that's why I tried Kubuntu (more straightforward). The fact that Kubuntu also fails to boot signals that it's not a USB stick/boot image problem.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the "*something like recovery mode*" ?

Comment: It's not a specific screen or something. What happens (e.g. when I try to boot Kubuntu) is that the Ubuntu are reinstalling. I am not getting an option for installing Kubuntu. Even if I try to boot another image with Ubuntu OS, I am also not getting an option to wipe-clean and install Ubuntu, it goes straight installing Ubuntu with the oem kernel, which is used in the preinstalled version in Thinkpads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing an Ubuntu installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277838/removing-an-ubuntu-installation)